# PHP - Don't use "\" in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wasn't exactly sure how to word this, but essentially what I need is so when I send a SELECT query in MySQL, it doesn't pay attention to the escape character ( \ ) in the search.  For example, if the name I am searching for is foo'bar and I send foo\'bar to the server, is there a way to make the server find foo'bar? This is the MySQL query currently:

```
function escape_data($data) {


    $data = mysql_escape_string (trim($data));
    $data = strip_tags($data);

return $data;

}

$champ1 = escape_data($_GET['champ1']);

 foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM champs WHERE name = '$champ1'") as $row) {
                $role_verify_1 = $row[$role];

             }
```

the only way I can get foo'bar to return is if I change it to foo\'bar in the MySQL database and I would like not to if it is possible.

Comment: Might want to fix your typo

Comment: Are you previously calling `addslashes()` or using the long-since-deprecated-please-don't-use-in-modern-code `magic_quotes_gpc`?

Comment: [`stripslashes()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) can be applied _before_ `mysql_real_escape_string()` but it would be better to fix your data source...

Comment: Switching to prepared statements is probably the best choice but my opinion is not valid so carry on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you want is [stripslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) before `mysql_real_escape_string`, however your real concern should be where the slashes are actually coming from - it looks like you might have [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on.  This is deprecated - check the link for instructions on disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax at PHP requires that.

For example;

```
   name = '$champ1'
```

Here you have a variable in `'` tags. But that variable includes `'` inside like foo'bar, its turn to that.

```
   name = 'foo'bar'
```

as you see php can't understand what is going on there. So it need to clear that problem like adding before `'` an `\`. And inserted item will have slashes before aphostropes.

As a solution you can delete the backslashes before you echo the variable.

```
$theVariable = str_replace("\", "", $theVariable);
```

Or you can use PHP's upper version's functions. like `stripslashes()` before you insert your data.

Good luck.